# Text data preprocessing in python

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp

I am working on extraction of positive, negative & neutral keyword in python.There are 10,000 comments in my comments remarks.txt file(encoded UTF-8).I want to import the text file, read the individual row of comments & extract words(tokenize) from the comments mentioned in column c2 & store it in a next adjacent column. I have written a small program calling get_keywords function in Python.I have created get_keywords() function but facing issues passing each row of the dataframe as argument & calling it using iterations  to provide keywords & store it in adjacent columns.

Codes are not providing expected column "tokens" with all the processed words in the df dataframe.

```
    import nltk
    import pandas as pd
    import re
    import string
    from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
    remarks = pd.read_csv('/Users/ZKDN0YU/Desktop/comments/New 
    comments/ccomments.txt')
    df = pd.DataFrame(remarks, columns= ['c2'])
    df.head(50)
    df.tail(50)

    filename = 'ccomments.txt'
    file = open(filename, 'rt', encoding="utf-8")
    text = file.read()
    file.close()

    def get_keywords(row):     
    # split into tokens by white space
      tokens = text.split(str(row))
    # prepare regex for char filtering
      re_punc = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
    # remove punctuation from each word
      tokens = [re_punc.sub('', w) for w in tokens]
    # remove remaining tokens that are not alphabetic
      tokens = [word for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]
    # filter out stop words
      stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
      tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
    # stemming of words
      porter = PorterStemmer()
      stemmed = [porter.stem(word) for word in tokens]
    # filter out short tokens
      tokens = [word for word in tokens if len(word) > 1]
      return tokens
      df['tokens'] = df.c2.apply(lambda row: get_keywords(row['c2']), 
       axis=1)
      for index, row in df.iterrows():
      print(index, row['c2'],"tokens : {}".format(row['tokens']))
```

Expected Output:- A Comments_modified file containing columns 1)index,2) c2(Comments) & 3)tokenized words for all rows of the dataframe having  10,000 comments.

Comment: what is `text` in `tokens = text.split(str(row))`?  `pd.readcsv` returns a data frame , so what is the purpose of `df = pd.DataFrame(remarks, columns= ['c2'])`? WHY ARE YOU AGAIN reading the`ccomments.txt` to a mother file, and how is it getting passed to the function?

Comment: Please igonre the text. It was a mistake. Acutually, I was trying different ways to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your text file `ccomments.txt` does not have any heading (i.e. data starts from first row itself) and has only one column data per row (i.e., text file only has comments), below code will return a list of words.

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import re
import string
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer


def get_keywords(row):     
    # split into tokens by white space
      tokens = row.split()
    # prepare regex for char filtering
      re_punc = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
    # remove punctuation from each word
      tokens = [re_punc.sub('', w) for w in tokens]
    # remove remaining tokens that are not alphabetic
      tokens = [word for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]
    # filter out stop words
      stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
      tokens = [w for w in tokens if w not in stop_words]
    # stemming of words
      porter = PorterStemmer()
      stemmed = [porter.stem(word) for word in tokens]
    # filter out short tokens
      tokens = [word for word in tokens if len(word) > 1]
      return tokens


df = pd.read_csv('ccomments.txt',header=None,names = ['c2'])                      
df['tokens'] = df.c2.apply(lambda row: get_keywords(row))
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, row['c2'],"tokens : {}".format(row['tokens']))
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! I tried these codes but getting this error.

File "<ipython-input-226-e8ce9b78bf28>", line 12, in get_keywords
    tokens = row.split()

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: just read text file to data frame using `df = pd.read_csv('ccomments.txt')`, and print out the total number of columns in the  data frame using `df.shape[1]`, if its more tan one , create a new data frame `df1 = df[['column_heading_of_comments_column']]', ten on `df1` do the rest. ERROR is because your current data frame has numbers (floats), you cannot `split()` numbers. can you provide sample of your dataset?